# LaTeX pgfplots use strings for barchart label from .csv

Tags: latex, pgf

I'm trying to use data from a .csv file to create a barchart with labels that are non-numeric. I've looked through a few older examples, but they seem large and clunky. I'm hoping there's a better way. Here's what I have so far as a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=x axis label,ylabel=y axis label]
\addplot [ybar] table [symbolic x coords=Month, y=Dozers, col sep=comma] {cnrldata.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \\
\end{document}
```

From this I of course get the error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'May 14' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'May 14'.. ... y=Dozers, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
```

The data in the table looks like this:

```
Month, Dozers,
January, 0.85,
February, 0.7,
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `symbolic x coords` is wrong.  Read the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf).

*Tip:*  You are more likely to get such questions answered on [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$ axis label},
    ylabel={$y$ axis label},
    symbolic x coords={January,February,March,April,May},
    ]
    \addplot [ybar] table [x=Month, y=Dozers, col sep=comma] {
      Month, Dozers
      January, 0.85
      February, 0.7
      March,    0.6
      April,    0.9
      May,      0.4
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]